# No WiFi with ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, 19.10

I just updated my DELL XPS-13-7390 device from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 19.10. So far, wifi worked fine without any problems! Now it says that there is no adapter WLAN available and connecting to the internet os no longer possible. I did try a number of repairs strategies found in the net, but nothing worked. 
Besides the WLAN, ubuntu 19.10 seems to work fine.

Comment: Was your 18.04 to 19.10 a re-install? or untested/unsupported upgrade?  Were you using the HWE kernel on 18.04?  (ie. there won't be any change moving to 19.10) or GE kernel (thus you moved from 4.15 to 5.3)?  If you didn't re-install, did wifi work on the 'live' media before install?  *FYI: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS had intended tested & thus supported upgrade paths; one was to 18.10 (now EOL & no longer possible), and it will be tested to upgrade to 20.04 (before 20.04.1's release as it's unsupported until then)*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

See the output of "sudo lshw", find your card model and then search in apt for your model, probably you have a driver for it.

For example if you have an Atheros AR9271:

apt search ath

firmware-ath9k-htc/eoan,eoan 1.4.0-97-g75b3e59+dfsg-3 all
  QCA ath9k-htc Firmware

you should install that driver (kernel module) with:

apt install firmware-ath9k-htc

Sometimes i had problems because i had an incompatible module installed and the solution was eliminate it:

First you search in your instralled packages related to your wifi model:

dpks -l|grep -i ath

and then you delete the incompatible driver:

dpkg --purge firmware-ath9k-htc

I have used "firmware-ath9k-htc" for the example but you must search for your model of wifi card with "sudo lshw"